# Delete surrounding whitespace in vim

Tags: vim

I'm using the awesome https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround plugin to surround words with parenthesis, for example I often use: `viws<space><space>` to surround a word with spaces.

What I'm missing is the opposite of this, that is, deleting surrounding spaces around a word.

The most common use for me is function arguments like
foo(bar) vs foo( bar ) depending on code style.

Does anyone know a nice way to do this?

Comment: Does `ds<space>` work? The README provides `ds"` as a mechanism to remove the `"` delimiters on an example.

Comment: It does not unfortunately. Good observation though.

Comment: I find it funny that you find the `viws<space><space>` command to be a simpler solution than all the alternatives, including using the arrow keys and backspace!

Comment: hmm..yeah..never thought about it... funny how peoples brains work differently :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: This solution requires the surround plugin referenced in the question.

For your specific situation you could do the following:

```
cs()
```

This changes `foo( bar )` to `foo(bar)`, however, it is not a general solution to your problem.

Comment: kind of elegant.. weird but elegant :)

Comment: what is that supposed to do? It does nothing for me

Comment: If you don't have the surround plugin noted in the OP then it won't do what is expected.  With surround, `csXY` says to "change the surrounding characters X with surrounding characters Y", the `(` is defined as "surrounding parentheses with a padding space", and the `)` is defined as "surrounding parentheses without a padding space".

Comment: Isn't there a way to configure the surround plugin to not use the extra spaces around the () ?

Comment: can you explain more on " surrounding parens with a padding space" ? why the padding space? @RandyMorris
it works, but I think I don't understand it completely.

Comment: @nabn I'm not sure I understand your question.  OP was asking for a way to change `foo( bar )` to `foo(bar)`.  The surround plugin provides a way to insert parens as `(  )` or as `()` depending on which map you use.  The key sequence in my answer is `c`hanging the `s`urrounding `(` --with the extra spaces-- into `)` which is parens without extra spaces.

Comment: I understand the question, and the answer works. I just meant to ask why ( includes the padding space? (I think it's more intuitive for a opening paren to be just an opening paren, w/o the space). I'm not sure if it's a vim default.

Comment: @nabn Ahh I understand now.  These mappings are provided by a third party script so you'd have to ask the author what their reasoning was.

Comment: So it's not the default. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

I often productively procrastinate in search of vim plugins too, when I could just define a mapping for this.

```
nnoremap <leader>dd F<space>xf<space>x
```

**EDIT** more information

- `<leader>` common key for user defined mappings (`,` is a good one)
- `dd` combination to use (any other mnemonic one will suffice)
- `F<space>x` search backwards for a space, then remove it
- `f<space>x` search forwards for a space, then remove it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just `BXElx` in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, perfect solution for me is the mapping provided by @puk, but using the keys @sarnold expected in the first place (what one would expect from surround plugin if it implemented this).

This is:

```
nnoremap ds<space> F<space>xf<space>x
```